# Mocking generic methods in Moq with interface

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I am trying to setup moq for the following generic interface but getting exception

```
 public interface IReadAccess<TEntity>
 {
     Task<IEnumerable<TEntity>> GetAll();
 }

var m = new Mock<IReadAccess<Foo>>(MockBehavior.Strict);

m.Setup(p => p.GetAll()).ReturnsAsync(new List<Foo>());

m.VerifyAll();
```

Getting bellow exception

```
Moq.MockException
  HResult=0x80131500
  Message=The following setups on mock
    'Mock<EPIC.CrossCutting.Interfaces.DAL.Framework.IReadAccess<EPIC.CrossCutting.DTOs.Data.Announcement.AnnouncementCrosscutDTO>:00000002>' 
  were not matched:
IReadAccess<AnnouncementCrosscutDTO> p => p.GetAll()

  Source=Moq
  StackTrace:
   at Moq.Mock.VerifyAll()
   at EPIC.Tests.Business.Rules.Announcements.AnnouncementPlanning.CrosscutsProgrammaticActivitiesValidationRuleServiceTests.<ExecuteSuccessTest>d__5.MoveNext() 
in D:\dev\main\Tests\EPIC.Tests.Business.Rules\Announcements\AnnouncementPlanning\CrosscutsProgrammaticActivitiesValidationRuleServiceTests.cs:line 108
```

Comment: Can you fix your code snippet so that we can see how your mock was set up?

Comment: Is there some code between `Setup` and `VerifyAll` that actually calls the `GetAll`method?

Comment: Please read [MCVE] guidance and [edit] post to show code that matches and reproduces your error message. Currently code is clearly some simplification that can't result in error shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your test is failing correctly because you try to verify that GetAll() was called even though you haven't actually called it.

It'll pass if you call the method in your test or in the code your are testing.

```
[Fact]
public async Task Test1()
{
    var m = new Mock<IReadAccess<Foo>>(MockBehavior.Strict);
    m.Setup(p => p.GetAll()).ReturnsAsync(new List<Foo>());

    var result = await m.Object.GetAll();

    m.VerifyAll();
}
```

The clue was in your error message:
Message=The following setups on mock .... were not matched:
IReadAccess p => p.GetAll()

Comment: Thanks Connell , this is working expected but I have simillar method    public interface IReadAccess<TEntity>
 {
     Task<IEnumerable<TEntity>> GetAll();
 }

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Connell , this is working expected but I have simillar method

```
public interface IReadAccess<TEntity>  
{  
    Task<IEnumerable<TEntity>> GetAll();   
    Task<IEnumerable<TEntity>> Find(FormattableString whereClause, object whereClauseObject);

}
```

and trying to setup

```
var m = new Mock<IReadAccess<Foo>>(MockBehavior.Strict);
m.Setup(x => x.Find($"ID = @ID", new { ID = 5 })).ReturnsAsync(new List<Foo>());
var result = await m.Object.Find($"ID= @ID", new { ID = 5 });
m.VerifyAll();
```

after made some changes on the existing code , now setup is working fine but getting error on actual service when it is calling for from test, updated code

```
var test = new Test {ID = 5};
object whereClause = new { ID = test.ID };
            FormattableString formattableString = $"ID = @ID";

            m.Setup(x => x.Find(formattableString, whereClause)).ReturnsAsync(new List<Foo>());

 var ruleServiceOutput = await this.testValidationRuleService.ExecuteAsync(test);
```

Actual Code

```
public async Task<IRuleServiceOutput<bool>> ExecuteAsync(Test test)
        {
            var errors = new List<string>();

            object whereClause = new { ID = test.ID };
            FormattableString formattableString = $"ID = @ID";

            var output = (await m.Find(formattableString, whereClause)).ToArray();

            return new RuleServiceOutput<bool>(output.Errors.IsEmpty(), output.Errors);
        }
```

'IReadAccess`1.Find(ID = @ID, { ID = 5 }) invocation failed with mock behavior Strict.
All invocations on the mock must have a corresponding setup.'

After setting MockBehavior.Default everything working expected :)

Comment: Try setting up the mock like this `m.Setup(x => x.Find(It.IsAny<FormattableString>(), It.IsAny<object>())).ReturnsAsync(new List<Foo>());`